# how to use a sql database table for 2 difference cases? (C#)

Tags: c#

in C# ::I need to use a table for 2 school classes, i am using a table for one now, but i need to use a table same as this, for another school class. how can i do this?
how many DataAdapter, DataSet or SqlConnection do I need?

Comment: if it's the same, why cant you put it in the same table?

Comment: It sounds like you might be new to databases (correct me if I'm wrong).  Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish, maybe with some example data that you want to store in the table?  Sometimes related data with small differences can be stored in the same table by using optional columns or flags to mark the different types.

Comment: for me your question is not clear."i am using a table for one now, but i need to use a table same as this". so you want to duplicate the table?  And if not duplicate, then what you want to achieve? a demo design of your plan will be helpful...i believe

Comment: i need to duplicate a connection to my DB. and i'm new to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the exact structure of your database surely don't help to answer precisely to your question but considering the info you provided, if you use the same database engine for both of your tables, you can use one SqlConnection and as many DataAdapter, DataSet as you wish.

But you should establish a correct design of your database first and submit it would help everybody to give you a better answer than this one:-)